# Difference in the Order of Applying Quantum Gates in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, ising-model

I've been experimenting with Qiskit and came across a scenario where I'm uncertain about the effects of the order in which I apply quantum gates.

Imagine we have the Hamiltonian [image]

Which one would be the correct implementation

```
for j in range(0, N_qubit, 2):
    qc.rzz(U, j, j+1)
    qc.rxx(-J, j, j+1)
    qc.ryy(-J, j, j+1)
```

Or

```
for j in range(0, N_qubit, 2):
    qc.rzz(U, j, j+1)

for j in range(0, N_qubit, 2):
    qc.rxx(-J, j, j+1)

for j in range(0, N_qubit, 2):
    qc.ryy(-J, j, j+1)
```

Or any other form?
Since rotation gates are not commutative between themselves I couldn't figure it out which one would be correct.